# Copy list attachment to document library using REST

Tags: workflow, copy-item

Is it possible to copy an attachment on a list item to a document library within the same site using SPD workflows and the REST api?

I have tried using the copyto function, but I cannot get it to work.

I have the relative url of the attachment itself (using another REST call).

All other solutions is off the table, I cannot use any 3rd party solutions or scripting or anything.

BR
Morten

Comment: possibly useful? http://sympmarc.com/2016/04/20/uploading-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists-using-rest/

Comment: @EricAlexander
Unfortunately not :-(

The target of that post is to upload the attachment to the list item itself, not to upload it to a document library (Which is seperate to the list) - at least that's how I read the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes getting away and coming back wth fresh eyes is a good thing. I have made it work using the copyto function.

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('folder/filename.txt')/copyto(strnewurl='sites/sitesname/libraryname/filename.txt',boverwrite=false)
```

I still have an issue to fix though, the file get corrupted and cannot open (Happens on xlsx and docx files - but not txt files) - but that should be possible to fix I'm pretty sure!

Comment: Oh scratch that last comment as well. It seem everything now works perfectly.